# Git merge open pull-request based on its ID

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

Is it possible to merge open pull-request based on its id via command line? I'm able to list opened pull request based on curl 'https://api.github.com/search', which returns back open PRs with their IDs. I would like to merge some of PRs, ideally based on their IDs which are in response, but I couldn't find any way how to do it.

Comment: You could use the github cli? https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_merge

Comment: Althoug that works, it doesn't provide option to specify PR ID. I can specify only number of PR. But thanks anyway for this suggestion! :)